# How to get website to interact with phone?

Tags: mobile

## Is there any way to get my website to interact with my Phone?

I have made a website that acts as a chat room. Using AJAX, PHP, Jquery and the usual.

But I was wondering if there was anyway for the phone to react to a new message?

I have looked into maybe using Java Applets.

And the possible ways for the phone to react. I don't know what would be the easiest... Maybe open up the web app if the phone is off it?

*I am more interested in this for the educational purpose. So please don't slate me.*

Answer (score 0):

You would need to mention more details here, like which phone do you have?

You could send an SMS text message to your phone, that would be like an alert.
Regarding options of getting the app to open, that's probably more possible on the Android platform.  Your app could have a background checker, or use the push messaging to push a message to your phone.